# Determine if a window is visible or not using C#

Tags: c#, user32

I have a Console / Form hybrid application in C#, and at the moment, i have to rely on user32.dll to show/hide the console window. But I can't seem to find a way in which i can determine if the console window is hidden or visible (without storing the value myself)

Answer (score 22):

[IsWindowVisible Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-iswindowvisible):

> The IsWindowVisible function retrieves the visibility state of the specified window.

C# Signature from [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/IsWindowVisible.html):

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool IsWindowVisible(IntPtr hWnd);
```

Comment: That will not check whenever the window is in fact visible. Read the msdn article.

Comment: I think you need
[DllImport(USER32)]
public static extern bool IsIconic(IntPtr hWnd);

Comment: "Any drawing to a window with the WS_VISIBLE style will not be displayed if the window is obscured by other windows or is clipped by its parent window." - Which means this will return true regardless if it can be seen.

Comment: FYI (to get your window handle): `var source = new WindowInteropHelper(myWindow).Handle;`

Comment: how to set winForm Visible to true? at Program.cs, I try ShowWindow is Unsuccessful

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue now, solved it this way:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr WindowFromPoint(Point lpPoint);

var mainForm = this; // or any other form you like to check
bool windowIsInvisible =  
    WindowFromPoint(new Point(mainForm.Left, mainForm.Top)) != mainForm.Handle || // topleft invisible
    WindowFromPoint(new Point(mainForm.Left + mainForm.Width - 1, mainForm.Top)) != mainForm.Handle || // topright invisible
    WindowFromPoint(new Point(mainForm.Left, mainForm.Top + mainForm.Height - 1)) != mainForm.Handle || // downleft invisible
    WindowFromPoint(new Point(mainForm.Left + mainForm.Width -1, mainForm.Top + mainForm.Height -1)) != mainForm.Handle; // downright invisible
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this function in a C# console application to determine if the program was launched with or without a console window visible (e.g. via `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()` with `CreateNoWindow = true`).

```
public static bool IsConsoleVisible()
{
    try
    {
        return Console.WindowHeight > 0;
    }
    catch (System.IO.IOException ex)
    {
        if (ex.Message.Contains("The handle is invalid."))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

Perhaps this will apply.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have success with `IsWindowVisible`.

turns out I needed `IsIconic` which means "if window minimized"

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool IsIconic(IntPtr hWnd);

public static bool GetIsWindowMinimized(IntPtr hWnd)
{
    return IsIconic(hWnd);
}
```